# Passing a Var from Class to Include

Tags: php, function, variables, include, var

I have a function which I would like to use an include within, but I need all the vars which are public in the Class to be passed cleanly to the page layout include file.

The vars are passed to within the function, but not when passed to the include. Any easy suggestions to doing this?

```
private function printGraph() {
    /*
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost') {
        echo "<pre>\n";
        echo "Actual: ".$this->actual."\n";
        echo "Actual Bar: ".$this->actualbar."\n";
        echo "Attainable Bar: ".$this->attainablebar."\n";
        echo "Attainable: ".$this->attainable."\n";
        echo "ADSL2Calc: ".$this->adsl2calc."\n";
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    */

    //Adding the new look Tshooterlayout!
    include 'tshooterlayout14.php';

    // Actual Speed info and bar
    $actual=file_get_contents("inc/troubleshooter/tshoot3-actual.inc");
    $actual=sprintf($actual,$this->actual,$this->actualbar,$this->attainablebar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use $this:

**test.php**

```
<?php
class Test {
    public $foo = 'bar';

    public function testme(){
        include "include.php";
    }

}

$T = new Test();

$T->testme();
```

**include.php**

```
<?php
echo "You got your " . $this->foo ." in my foo!\n";
```

**Results**

```
$ php test.php
You got your bar in my foo!
```

Comment: Worked a charm! You are my hero.

One issue I now have, is that I am referencing to a function from within that function within the Include, but that is giving me a hard time - any ideas on this one?

    Noise ratio: Fatal error: Call to undefined function calculateSNR() in /var/www/ADSLGeek/inc/troubleshooter/tshooterlayout14.php on line 236